# STL like stuff in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

Is there anything like STL in Visual Basic , e.g a binary tree , quick sort

Do I have to implement those algorithms myself , does Microsoft provide any useful interface ?

Thanks  !

Comment: Trying to find a mapping from STL to the .NET collection classes and algorithms is not very productive.  They didn't try to mimic STL, nobody ever did.  Don't write your own, everything you'll ever need is already available.  Or can be easily leveraged with encapsulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [.NET Base Class Library (BCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_Class_Library)), which is part of the .NET Framework would be the equivalent.

There is no binary tree per se (although [some are implemented as trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)), but sorting is already handled.  There are plenty of sorts [Array.Sort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort.aspx), [List.Sort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx), [Linq OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) and plenty of collections that sort themselves.   See classes the [System.Collections.Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx) namespace.